# pandas sum up a column during merge

Tags: python, pandas

I need to merge a number of dataframes using pandas with the following properties:

- the dataframes always have the same columns, e.g. `name`, `type`, and `value`.
- the merge needs to take into account two columns, `name` and `type`, in order to identify matches
- the dataframes may have different numbers of rows.
- the other column,`value` in my example above, should result in one column after the merge. If both datasets had a row with the same `name` and `type`, then the result of `value` should be the sum of the values of each dataset.
- I do not care about the indexes of the rows.

For example, If I had the `DataFrame df1`:

```
df1:
      name type  value
    0  foo    A     11
    1  bar    B     12
```

and the `DataFrame df2`:

```
df2:
      name type  value
    0  foo    A     21
    1  bar    C     22
    2  baz    C     23
```

Then I want the result to be

```
result_want:
      name type  value
    0  foo    A     32
    1  bar    B     12
    2  bar    C     22
    3  baz    C     23
```

the best I found so far is how to do the merge, like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 
        "name": ["foo", "bar"], 
        "type": ["A", "B"],
        "value": [11, 12]
    })


df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 
        "name": ["foo", "bar", "baz"], 
        "type": ["A", "C", "C"], 
        "value": [21, 22, 23]
    })

result = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on=['name', 'type'])
print(result)
```

gives

```
 name type  value_x  value_y
0  foo    A     11.0     21.0
1  bar    B     12.0      NaN
2  bar    C      NaN     22.0
3  baz    C      NaN     23.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) then [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) here

```
out = pd.concat([df1, df2])
out.groupby(['name', 'type'], as_index=False).sum()

  name type  value
0  bar    B     12
1  bar    C     22
2  baz    C     23
3  foo    A     32
```